# How to invoke the non-getter methods in sightly?

Tags: java, aem, sightly

I want to invoke non-getter methods in sightly, is that possible?

For example, `HashMap.size()`

Comment: Use Java Reflection API. See documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: No need to use reflection...

Answer (score 1):

You can call any publicly accessible method on your Use objects or on the [global objects](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/sightly/global-objects.html) available to your Sightly scripts, as long as the method doesn't need parameters.

For more details about the implementation of discovering the available methods on your objects you could check [RenderUtils.java](https://github.com/apache/sling/blob/org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly-1.0.18/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/scripting/sightly/impl/utils/RenderUtils.java#L326).

Comment: Radu - Please take the time to read over the [markdown guide in help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) so that you learn how to format your posts for readability.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you can do `<p>${hashMap.size}</p>` now using this with arguments I have absolutely no clue :)

I think that Gabriel Walt would be the best person to ask...

Comment: You can not go this way, because HashMap is not a Sling Model (class which marked by org.apache.sling.models.annotations.Model annotation).

Comment: Worked for me for the last two years :)